# Is it bad form to have a different number of audio tracks from video tracks?

Tags: premiere, tracks

In Premier when adding a new Audio or Video track it wants to add both. In industry is it considered good form to leave empty tracks, say:

- V2 Movie Clip
- V1 Title
- A1 BG Music
- A2 nothing

Or is it better form to delete those extra tracks or not add them to begin with so instead it looks like

- V2 Movie Clip
- V1 Title
- A1 BG Music

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always avoid excess tracks.  You can add as many or few tracks of each types as you want in "Add Tracks..." Simply adjust the number of tracks to be added by clicking on the number.  It defaults to 1 video and 1 audio track, but that can easily be changed each time you add tracks.

You can also add an individual track to either by right clicking in the header area and saying Add Track.

As far as industry standards go, I've never heard of a standard and I've never known anyone to think anything of having unused tracks, but cleanliness is always a plus.  There is certainly no standard to intentionally use excess tracks, but in my experience nobody is going to think anything if there are a few excess tracks either.  Generally cleaning up after yourself does look a little more professional though.

Comment: Ya so far I've been avoiding them too but is that the industry standard? If I ever have to work on a team for video editing does everyone avoid the excess tracks?

Comment: @Ryan - updated to address industry standards.  I didn't mention it because there aren't any other than just general cleanliness and professionalism, but I've never heard a strong opinion against the presence of 1 or 2 unused tracks.

Comment: edited question with an additional one instead of making a whole one

Comment: @Ryan - generally it is preferred to separate questions when possible to make it easier for others to find answers in the future.  That question is really going to require a separate answer too because it is a non-trivial answer.

Comment: will do, thought it might be fairly trivial like this one seems to have been